# how to customize mixins in tapestry?

Tags: eclipse, maven, mixins, tapestry

My english is not good. I have a customized `mixins` in `tapestry`.

Of course, in package `mixins`, using `maven` and `eclipse`. And it work. I want to use it in another maven project.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.chit.mymixins</groupId>
        <artifactId>mixins</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency
```

but it does not work. I know this may not be right.

The customized `mixins` does not in a package named `mixins` in current project. I do not know the right configuration.

This is my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a library mapping for your mixins. Read this [article](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-libraries.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now my mixins is available, but how to configure my module to autoload? There is no source code about pom.xml on step 5.

Comment: I got my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, sody. My project does not work yet. Thanks in advance. My configuration as below:public static void contributeComponentClassResolver(Configuration<LibraryMapping> configuration) {configuration.add(new LibraryMapping("chit", "com.chit.newautocomplete"));}

Comment: <plugin><groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId><artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId><configuration><archive><manifestEntries><Tapestry-Module-Classes>com.chit.newautocomplete.services.AppModule</Tapestry-Module-Classes></manifestEntries></archive></configuration></plugin>

Comment: I have a customized component for test and it works well, But my customized mixins can not. Any configuration else is necessary? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I get the answer. It would be used like this:    `t:mixins="chit/mymixins"`